# Using a compact URI in Jena

Tags: java, jena, n-triples

I'm using Jena to read an ontology and it's working really well so far. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how to use compact uris that I've defined in the model. I've defined the prefixes using the model's `setNSPrefix(String prefix, String uri)` method. When I try to retrieve statements using the prefix, I get nothing. Also, when I do successfully retrieve a Statement, it contains the full uri instead of the compact one that I defined. It will even do it for the xsd uri `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#`

For example, I'm using the uri `http://www.example.com#`, I've defined my prefix mapping as `ex`, and my Statement is `http://www.example.com#father http://www.example.com#parentOf http://www.example.com#child` where father is the subject, parentOf is the predicate, and child is the object. If I try to retrieve it using `ex:father` I get no results, and when I do get the Statement back the full uri is there for the subject, predicate, and object. I've seen it use the prefix instead of the uri when I do `model.write(OutputStream)`, but that isn't particularly helpful for me. Am I able to use the prefix as a substitute for the uri like I've been trying to do, or is that not something Jena will provide for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When I try to retrieve statements using the prefix, I get nothing.*

You can't do, e.g.,

```
model.getResource("ex:foo")`
```

You have to do

```
model.getResource("http://example.org/foo");
```

You can make that simpler, of course, by

```
String EX = "http://example.org/";
model.getResource(EX+"foo");
```

The prefixes are really just for making the serializations nicer to read and write.

Comment: So when I'm getting a Statement based on the resource, is there any way to show the prefix instead of the full uri, or is it in a similar situation? For example, statement.getObject() will return `http://www.example.com#child` when I really want `ex:child`.

Comment: There's no general way to do that.  What if, for instance, there were two prefixes defined in the model:  "ex: http://www.example.com#" and "ex2: ex: http://www.example.com#chi"?  Would you want ex:child or ex2:ld?  What if there's no prefix?  What if it's a non-abbreviatable IRI?  If you want something like that, you're going to have to roll-your-own by checking whether a given IRI can be abbreviated by any of the prefixes declared in the model.

Comment: Alright, that's what I figured I would have to do. My thought was to grab the prefix mapping from the model, use that to see if the uri has a prefix, and then write it as that prefix instead of the full uri.

Comment: "if the uri has a prefix" It could have more than one, as well.